# how to recover the temporary layer saved accidentally as xlsx file

Tags: qgis, data-loss

As the topic. I created a temporary Point layer to calculate and mark objects passing through flowing waters (rivers, streams) on the OSM map.

I accidentally saved my temporary layer as xlsx, I only have the object number saved in the file.

I am using QGIS 3.24.1-Tisler.

Is there any way to recover lost data, such as the location of objects on the map?

Comment: directly recovering the location data from the accidentally saved xlsx file in QGIS isn't possible